# Props Immutability in react

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I am trying to understand immutable behavior of props and done a POC for this.
I have passed an object to child component and changed that object's property  (props) in child component.
My code worked without giving any error. If props is immutable it should error out.
Below is the code example
https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-chihiro-wdcnzg?file=/src/ChildComponent.js

Please help me to understand this concept.

I have tried above POC

Comment: Understand what concept specifically?

Comment: It’s not enforced; it’s up to you to ensure.

Comment: Props are not immutable, but re-rendering only occurs when new references (for arrays, objects, Maps, etc) or values (for strings/booleans/numbers) are present for a given prop. If you change an attribute on a prop directly, it will not re-render.